# Making list items stretch to 100% inside a unordered list

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the li's inside this ul to stretch to the width of the ul. I want the whole ul to be shifted to the left, so it touches the div class header-title. I want the nav links in the menu to be at the bottom, not the top -"vertical-align: bottom;" doesn't work.

I can't seem to figure it out.

EDIT, forgot to paste the link, [jsfiddle.net/5uxnowdb/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/5uxnowdb/1/)

HTML-

```
    <!-- Begin >> Container -->
    <div class="container">

        <div class="header-photo">
            <img src="img/alan-headshot-round.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="header-title font-title">
            <span style="color: #ffcc00;">A</span>M
        </div>

        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">BOOKS</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
                <li><a href="services.html">SERVICES</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT ME</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- End >> Container -->

</div>
<!-- End >> Wrapper -->
```

CSS-

```
body {
    background-color: #3e4648;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center; /* For IE6 purposes to fix bug */ 
}

div.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
}

div.container {
    height: 25px;
    left: 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: 35px;
    width: 800px;
}


/* BEGIN TITLE */

div.font-title {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

div.header-photo {
    background-color: #1c3641;
    height: 72px;
    width: 100px;
    vertical-align: center;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

div.header-title {
    background-color: #1c3641;
    height:60px;
    width: 240px;
    left: 92px;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 12px;
}

/* END TITLE */

/* BEGIN NAVIGATION */

#menu {
    font-family: calibri;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 72px;
    width: 450px;
    background-color: #2e2f30;
    text-align: center;
    left: 330px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}

#menu ul {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 72px;
    width: 410px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px dotted green;
}

#menu li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 72px;
    background-color: #2e2f30;
    display: inline;
    width: 80px;
}

#menu li:hover {
    background-color: #353a3c;
}

#menu a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some context? Your code? A live demo?

Comment: Please show your HTML and  CSS that pertains to your `li`, `ul`, and `div`, if any. Please do an example, preferably in jsfiddle.net.

Comment: You need to add code to your question as it needs to be self-sufficient.  Please refer to [ask] for guidelines on how to improve your question and get help faster.  Welcome to SO

Answer (score 0):

Remove ul's padding and li's margins, if any.

```
ul {
   padding: 0;
}
ul  li {
   margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very tough to answer without code, but by default li's have a margin-left added through the USER-AGENT-STYLESHEET (browser defaults). If you would like them to start aligned from the left, remove that manually by changing that margin. Or you could use an additional stylesheet like a normalize.css.

Furthermore, if you want the element to be the width of the parent, change the display to inline-block and width to 100%.

If you'd like more info I suggest also looking at a netTuts or css-tricks for fundamentals about how to use CSS.

Good luck.